# Connecting to Oracle DB using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I want to connect Oracle Database in .net platform using C#

and here is some code

```
  _connectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=yong;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX";

  using (OdbcConnection sqlConnection = new OdbcConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter())
                {
                    try {
                        adapter.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection);
                        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
                        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = _commandTimeOut;
                        adapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
                        adapter.Fill(dtResult);
                        }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
               }
            }
```

when I try this code, it throws error like

" msdaora.1' provider is not registered on the local machine "

I don't get what is a problem and how to fix this.
How do I register a msdaora.1 provider on the local machine and
what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have a oracle odbc driver isntalled on your machine? I don't think your connection string is correct.  Go look here http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading and installing the Oracle Data Access Components. Here are links to the [32 bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html) and [64 bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) versions. Also, just from personal experience, I would use the oracle OleDb adapter instead of that one, but that's because I've had trouble connecting to RAC clusters with other adapters.

Edit: You're also going to run into problems when you deploy the app to an environment that doesn't have ODAC installed, so here some further [suggested reading](http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=232).